# NSPredicate: "Unable to parse the format string '%@'"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, predicate

I'm trying to build a query string or predicate but I keep getting this error,

Basically what I can't understand is that this works fine:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name contains[cd] 'o')"];
```

But this:

```
NSString *predString =  @"(name contains[cd] 'o')";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@", predString];
```

throws this:

> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "%@"'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`%@` is not a predicate format, it's a string format.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predString];
```

Comment: This is not a proper solution to the question. It opens your code up to all sorts of format string injection attacks in case the `predString` contains user-supplied data (e.g., `account == "user%K%@<bindata>"` with `user%K%@<bindata>` being an attacker-supplied datum). You should NEVER EVER use anything but a constant string in any of the `...withFormat:` methods.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, %@ can't be used everywhere in predicate construction. But it can be useful to be able to construct the predicate ahead of time. You can use a #define to define all or at least the constant part of it:

```
    #define kPredicateStr_MovieItem_MoviesInCatalog @"((wishList == NO) AND ((tvEpisode == NO) || (tvEpisode == YES AND (ANY tvSeries.genres.name LIKE 'TV Movie'))))"
```

Then either supply it as-is:

```
    itemsViewController.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:kPredicateStr_MovieItem_MoviesInCatalog];
```

or add to it:

```
    NSString *predStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ AND (%@ CONTAINS \"%@\")", kPredicateStr_MovieItem_MoviesInCatalog, titleForSearch, searchString];

    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predStr];
```